# FM radio for Xperia arc S with CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sony-xperia-arc, fm-radio

How do I listen to radio on an [Xperia arc S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Ericsson_Xperia_arc_S)?

I use [CyanogenMod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyanogenMod) (version 7.2.0), which does not include an FM radio app.

Comment: Which version of CM are you referring to?

Comment: You could probably grab the app off the original ROM if it's not tied to other system services, though there is the question of whether it would rely on drivers not present in CM.

Comment: @t0mm13b CyanogenMod 7.2.0, but i don't think it is relevant.

Comment: @Matthew how do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FreeXperia team have added FM radio in their latest CM nightlies, and it seems to work.

Comment: Which nightly is this? CM9? I tried cm-7-20131222-FXP-anzu.zip, but this does doesn't include support for the FM radio.

Comment: I am using `FXP231-cm-10-20130805-UNOFFICIAL-anzu`, anything newer *should* work. Don’t recall any CM7 builds having FM support.

Comment: I tried a CM9 build where I got the radio to work, but I would prefer CM7 as it's much less resource hungry. I did find a CM7.2 build for the Xperia Mini (MiniCM) that includes FM radio support, but haven't managed to get it working on my Arc.

Comment: @Brent IIRC CM7 was already discontinued by the time they got the FM radio working.

Answer (score 2):

The programming support for the FM radio service that is in place within CyanogenMod 7.2, is probably not compatible with the chipset used in Xperia arc S. Hence the omission of the FM radio, it supports only [Broadcom BCM4325](http://www.broadcom.com/products/Bluetooth/Bluetooth-RF-Silicon-and-Software-Solutions/BCM4325), [Silicon Industry 4708 and 4709](http://www.silabs.com/products/audiovideo/fmreceivers/Pages/Si470809.aspx), and lastly [Texas Instrument WL1271](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/wtbu/wtbuproductcontent.tsp?templateId=6123&navigationId=12762&contentId=29993&DCMP=wtbu_connectivity&HQS=Other%20OT%20wilink6).

Looking at [pdadb.net](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=3097&view=1&c=sony_ericsson_xperia_arc_s__lt18__lt18i_se_ayame) for the specification of the handset - the chipset is not documented, so it's proprietary in which case CyanogenMod 7.2 has no support for it, hence the omission of the FM radio.

The best bet would be to find the original stock ROM dump of that here on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=970643&page=1), extract the radio app (could be called `FMRadio.apk`) from it and push that across to your handset.

***Edit:*** As confirmed by the OP, there are dead links galore on XDA. However, I found another [linky](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1590121&page=8) that may do it (Post #72). (*That's err... ICS ROM dump... it might be worth a try.*)

***Edit 2:*** Here's [the radio stuff](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?nh2c4isj2n7jvoo), you need to install it in this fashion.

After unzipping the archive, there are two files, `FmRxService.apk`, and `Radio.apk`. Plug in the cable to the handset and enter the commands,

```
adb install FmRxService.apk
adb install Radio.apk
```

The radio should now appear in your applications drawer, fingers crossed and good luck. There is no guarantee it will work either...

Comment: dead link (6 more to go...)

Comment: @kinokijuf Let me check for you :)

Comment: the ICS apps obviusly don’t work

Comment: Do a bit of google-fu to find the right ROM for your handset, am sure there's mirrors of it lying around :) or repackaged in a glorified variant of stock ROM over on XDA.

Comment: actually, am curious, since I have an Xperia Mini 2011 model, would that work on your Arc?... I can pull it off it if you want for you to try out?

Comment: trying won’t hurt…

Comment: It shows something like this:
 pkg: /data/local/tmp/FmRxService.apk

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

Comment: Right, (you are rooted?), if so, try this final attempt... `adb push FmRxService.apk /system/app` and `adb push Radio.apk /system/app`, other than that no can do :)

Comment: Tried, it didn't work.